# procedure with multi where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

have the following table

```
table TableAB(
        ColumnA int,
        ColumnB nvarchar(50)
)
```

i need to create a procedure which returns **ColumnA**, **ColumnB** and takes two parameters (in real life count of parameters more then  20). All searches should work with wildcard "%".

```
procedure has input parameters
        @ColumnA int,
        @ColumnB nvarchar(50)
```

i have two approaches

1.

```
select ColumnA,ColumnB from TableAB
where 
     ColumnA like 
     case  @ColumnA
        when @ColumnA NULL then ColumnA
        else '%' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@ColumnA)+'%'
     end
     and
     ColumnB like 
     case  @ColumnB
        when @ColumnB NULL then ColumnB
        else '%' + ColumnB +'%'
     end
```

2.

```
 DECLARE @TabWhereConditions TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Condition VARCHAR(MAX))
    ...
    SET @ParamDefenition = '@pColumnA int, @pColumnB nvarchar(50)'

    IF(NOT @ColumnA IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TabWhereConditions(Condition) 
        VALUES('ColumnA like ' + '''%' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@ColumnA) + '%''') 
    END 
    IF(NOT @ColumnB IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TabWhereConditions(Condition) 
        VALUES('ColumnA like ' + '''%' + @ColumnB + '%''')  
    END  

    DECLARE CondCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Condition FROM @TabWhereConditions
    OPEN CondCursor

    SET @WhereString = ''
    FETCH NEXT FROM CondCursor INTO @WhereCondition
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereString = @WhereString + @WhereCondition + ' AND '

        FETCH NEXT FROM CondCursor INTO @WhereCondition
    END

    CLOSE CondCursor
    DEALLOCATE CondCursor

    SET @WhereString =  SUBSTRING(@WhereString,1, LEN(@WhereString)-4)

    SET @SqlCommand = '
    SELECT 
      ColumnA,
      ColumnB
    FROM TableAB 
    WHERE ' + @WhereString 


    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlCommand, @ParamDefenition, 
        @pColumnA = @ColumnA, 
        @pColumnB = @ColumnB,
```

Which approach is better ? first or second , or your suggestion 
**Note:** i need solution for situation when procedure can take  from 1 up to 20 parameters, each call can get different  number of parameters

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields...

Comment: Generally, the approach that doesn't use cursors is better.  Period.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have up to 20 parameters , why the first approach better ?

Comment: [Please read this in full](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand  since each time i use a different number of parameters, execution plan created after first call, might not be effective for second call. That is why i need to care about  " Different plans optimized for different parameter combinations."     It would be correctly to use approach with EXEC sys.sp_executesql sql, params, ..

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to use something along these lines

```
select ColumnA,ColumnB from TableAB
where (@columnA is null or ColumnA like '%'+CONVERT(varchar(10),@ColumnA)+'%' and
      (@columnB is null or ColumnB like '%'+CONVERT(varchar(10),@ColumnB)+'%'
```

As noted in [this](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) Aaron Bertrand blog post, it is a good idea to make it dynamic T-SQL. Therefore, you may use `sys.sp_executesql` to run the above statement.

Comment: The problem is, with 20 optional parameters, every single call is going to run with a query plan optimized for a very specific combination of parameters and their values (modeled after the very first time the call was made).

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are right, for that reason on these queries you should add option(recompile), so the query plan is recalculated every time, after replace the parameters with their values.

Comment: @Marc that's kind of a blunt hammer too. What if 90% of the time the same set of parameters is used? I'd rather have a query plan individually optimized for a specific set of parameters. That can be reused whenever that same set of parameters is passed however, if that one has parameters that are prone to parameter sniffing due to skew or perpetually outdated stats, *then* you can add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` for those specific cases. Best of both worlds. You certainly don't need recompile when the only parameter is the primary key, for example.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, I didn't read your blog. As you say, best of both worlds.

Comment: Marc I think you should. Folks like @AaronBertrand , Paul White, Brent Ozar, Paul Randal, and other SQL Server MVPs almost always back their blogs with repeatable tests. Pretty valuable, FREE, knowledge.

Comment: @scsimon Yes, I have done it now, and as I have already said, he's right, his article explains the best of both worlds.

Comment: @RadimBača could you post how procedure should look like with use of sys.sp_executesql. because your code snippet more related to "when statement". i find it useful , but this is only part of answer

Answer (score 2):

You can create execute stored procedure or query as shown below in case of multiple where condition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchUserPermission]
@UserId bigint,
@ParentModuleId Bigint
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON

        Declare @strSQLQuery AS VARCHAR(3000) =null;       
        Declare @strCriteria AS VARCHAR(1000)=null;

        BEGIN        
            SET @strCriteria = ' WHERE 1=1' 
           IF(@UserId > 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @strCriteria=@strCriteria + ' AND UserId =' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@UserId)
            END

        IF( @ParentModuleId > 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @strCriteria=@strCriteria + ' AND ParentModuleId=' + Convert(varchar,@ParentModuleId)
            END

           SET @strSQLQuery ='Select * From (
                    SELECT 
                        *
                    FROM Module_Mst
                    LEFT outer join UserPermissions_Mst 
                    on UserPermissions_Mst.ModuleId=Module_Mst.moduleId AND  Module_Mst.IsVisible=1
           ' +@strCriteria + ' ) AS TempUserPermission'

        if (LEN(@strCriteria) > 0 )
            BEGIN
                SET  @strSQLQuery = @strSQLQuery   + ' ORDER By OrderNo '     
            END 
     END 

       --Print(@strSQLQuery)      

     EXEC (@strSQLQuery)                        
END
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: [`CONVERT(VARCHAR` without a length is bad](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), and also, why not just pass those as strongly-typed parameters? Concatenating user input to a query is just asking for trouble (unless you want to be [in this kind of news](https://www.computerworld.com.au/article/315418/sql_injection_attacks_led_massive_data_breaches/)).